# adding ValidationExpression to customvalidator in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, customvalidator

i have this ValidationExpression="(\d{1,}.{0,2} .{2,})|(.{2,} \d{1,}.{0,2})" used in regularexpression validator. I want to use the same one in a customvalidator. But customvalidator does not have option validationexpression. how can i add this in code or in tag. Please give me sample.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ASP.NET Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx) Class.

```
    protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {

          if (!Regex.IsMatch(args.Value,@"^(\d{1,}.{0,2} .{2,})|(.{2,} \d{1,}.{0,2})$"))
           {
               args.IsValid = false;
           }
           else
           {
             args.IsValid = true;
         }
}
```

Note: You will need *System.Text.RegularExpressions* namespace reference.